# Why is QLineEdit::setCursorPosition(int) selecting(highlighting) text?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qlineedit

I have an editable QComboBox that allows a user to type in a name for a new object and add it to the list.  They can also edit names for existing items in the list.  The problem is...say I have an item in the list called "AF" and I want to rename it to "ABCDEF".  My first problem was if I placed the cursor in between 'A' and 'F' and started typing the cursor would jump to the end after typing 1 letter.  So I would get "ABFCDE" unless I manually moved the cursor after each letter typed.

I fixed this by using

```
// slot connected to textEditChanged(QString) signal from QComboBox
void textChanged(const QString &text)
{
    int pos = QComboBox->lineEdit()->custorPosition();

    stuff...

    QComboBox->setItemText(idx, text);
    QComboBox->lineEdit()->setCursorPosition(pos);
}
```

and that works but unfortunately this caused a new problem.

setCursorPosition will subsequently select (highlight) all text beyond the new cursor location.  So in the "AF" to "ABCDEF" example... I place the cursor between 'A' and 'F', type B and the cursor stays after "AB" and before 'F' but 'F' is highlighted.  The next key press will replace the 'F' entirely.  It will highlight more than 1 character, it highlights every character to the right of the cursor after it is moved.

I tried this to no avail.

```
QComboBox->lineEdit()->deselect();
```

I also tried this just as a test and it incorrectly exhibited the same behavior.

```
QComboBox->lineEdit()->moveCursorBackward(false,2);
```

The false parameter is supposed to **not** select the text the cursor moves past but it does anyway.

Anyone have any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: "My first problem was if I placed the cursor in between 'A' and 'F' and started typing the cursor would jump to the end after typing 1 letter." => Why ? Do you handle other signals ?

Comment: I never could find out.  I resorted to forcing the cursor position to fix that problem.  And yes, I handle two other signals QComboBox::currentIndexChanged() and QComboBox::editingFinished() but neither of those get triggered while editing the lineEdit text.

Comment: Bad fix IMO. Beside what you've explained, what else is special with your combo ? Why is your var named `QComboBox`, that's a class name ...? Did you test removing your other signal handlers ?

Comment: The QComboBox variable name is rcsObjectNameCombo.  There isn't anything special about it really.  It just holds text names for rcs objects and allows the user to make a new one.  Other than that all it has to do is call functions to update the name throughout the GUI.  There are some 20+ signal handlers in the dialog but only 3 pertain to this QComboBox (the ones mentioned in the previous comment).

Comment: So `QComboBox->lineEdit()` is not the real code ? What happens if you comment out all signal handlers related to the combo ?

Comment: Real code is `ui_->rcsObjectNameCombo->lineEdit()`.  If I comment all the signal handlers it works like it should.  The line that caused the original problem is  `ui_->rcsObjectNameCombo->setItemText(comboIdx, text);` inside the `textChanged(text)` slot.  That's a critical part of how everything else is updated so I'll have to rework it I guess...thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes you have to rethink or explain the whole process to solve the root problem

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. Here's what solved it for me for anyone interested:

First connect the signal but make sure it is queued!

```
connect(_comboBox, SIGNAL(editTextChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(slotTextChanged(const QString&)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

and for the slot:

```
void ViewListWidget::slotViewNameChanged(const QString& /*name*/) {
    int index = _viewComboBox->currentIndex();

    int cursorPosition = _viewComboBox->lineEdit()->cursorPosition();

    // Since we are using a queued connection, get the current QLineEdit text
    // instead of relying on the signal argument, which might be out of sync
    QString name = _viewComboBox->lineEdit()->text();

    _viewComboBox->blockSignals(true);
    _viewComboBox->setItemText(index, name);
    _viewComboBox->blockSignals(false);

    _viewComboBox->lineEdit()->setCursorPosition(cursorPosition);
}
```

You should also probably disable auto-complete:

```
_comboBox->setCompleter(0);
```